# What is the forcefield strength of the Enterprise-D brig?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

What is the forcefield strength of a holding cell in the *Enterprise* brig? I prefer an in-universe answer, if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force fields were rated by intensity, ranging in strength from levels 1 through 10.

> Borg drone can be cut off from the Borg Collective if it is surrounded by a Starfleet level 10 force field.
> (DS9: "The Jem'Hadar"; TNG: "I Borg")

So Enterprise-D does support level 10 Force Fields.

Considering that brigs are designed to prevent prisoners from escaping, the force-field would probably be set at quite a high level, even if not 10, because prisoners of various species would have quite a few ways to attempt to breach them. Note that in some cases, there are examples when force fields are touched and have quite a feedback on the user, while on other occasions they do not damage too much the user touching them. This can be a big clue regarding their intensity.

So to clarify, Enterprise-D has the capability to deploy L10 force fields but it will probably only do so when deemed absolutely necessary, keeping the default brig levels to non-lethal but high intensity.

Comment: It can't be level 10 since they *uprate* the force field to level 10 when containing a Borg. Ergo it must be lower normally.

Comment: up to 11 then  https://xkcd.com/670/

Comment: @Valorum It makes sense that it would not be kept at its maximum level at all times, not only to limit the damage caused by getting into contact, but also to avoid wear on whatever components generate the shield, its power supply, etc.